# Background Service is getting killed after 10 minutes or so

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, background-service, foreground-service

I have created a service which is responsible for sending current location on server every 60 seconds.
I am using this as a foreground service, creating a foreground notification.
But its been noted that in some android devices if the phone screen is locked after 10 minutes or so the app along with the background services are getting killed and foreground notification also disappears with last log:

`---------------------------- PROCESS ENDED (1111) for package xyz ----------------------------`

I am failing to understand what is the issue as there are no crash reports in crashlytics and no issue in fetching location.

On searching what can be the issue google results suggest that this could be because of doze mode.

To counter it I have used wake locks and AlarmManager.setAndAllowWhileIdle to send alarm broadcast even in doze mode as per [this link](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby#doze-checklist), but even the alarm is not getting triggered.

`mAlarmManager.setAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 3 * 60 * 1000, pendingIntent);`

using STICKY in startcommand as well.

Can anyone help me as to what can be the issue, if anyone has come across this problem.

Comment: Whoever is using the phone has to go into their device settings and make your app exempt from battery optimizations. Using sensors or scanning location repeatedly make process a prime target for culling.

Comment: @Pawel - done that as well..added code to whitelist app from battery optimisation, still facing the issue.

Comment: https://dontkillmyapp.com/